# Letter-spacing applies in preview mode but not on the blog

Tags: css, tumblr

When I set the letter-spacing attribute of my post text, I can see the result in Tumblr's "Preview Mode" but the changes do not apply when I save my template and view it in real mode. I have tested this on IE, Chrome and Safari on both Windows and OS X. So I don't think it's a browser problem. This is how it correctly shows my changes in Preview mode.
[image]

And this is the bit I set my post text CSS:

```
#posts {
         border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
         font: 1.2em/1.6em  Arial, sans-serif;
         line-height:2;
         letter-spacing:2;
         max-width: 960px;
         min-width: 780px;
         padding: 0 32px;
         margin: 0 auto;
         list-style: none;
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`letter-spacing` requires units to be specified. These can be px, em, rem, percentage, etc.

See the following resources for more information:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing)
- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/)

Comment: You're welcome! I find it odd that the preview doesn't require units, but oh well.

Comment: A unit is required by CSS specifications, and according to them, the declaration must be ignored if the value is incorrect. This is what happens in browsers in “standards mode”. But in “quirks mode”, simulating old, broken browsers, the unit `px` is implied in situations like this.

Comment: @randak yes i find it odd as well tbh.